# Failed to configure AWSCognitoAuthPlugin Make sure your amplifyconfiguration.json is valid

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin

I'm working on project which uses Amplify Framework but i'm facing a problem with initialization when i launch app , i'm still beginner with aws , can anyone please help me with this issue , Thank you

- Error thrown

```
ConfigurationException{message=Failed to configure AWSCognitoAuthPlugin., cause=org.json.JSONException: No value for Default, recoverySuggestion=Make sure your amplifyconfiguration.json is valid.}
```

- Application class

```
  try {
            Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
            Log.i("mako", "Initialized Amplify")
            Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession({ result: AuthSession ->
                Log.i("mako", "Loggeado:"+result.toString()) })
            { error: AuthException ->
                Log.e("mako", "With Error:" + error.toString())
            }
        } catch (error: AmplifyException) {
            Log.e("mk", "Could not initialize Amplify", error)
        }
```

- Amplify Configuration File

[image]

PS : PoolId , AppClientId and Region have correct values , just hid them for privacy purposes .